# Mongoose dup key

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm getting a duplicate key error and not sure why.

I have the following schema:

```
var walletSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    currencyName : {type : String, required : true, unique : true},
    amount : {type : Number, default : 0}
}, {strict : false});

// define the schema for our user model
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    local : {
        username    : { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
        password    : { type: String, required: true, unique : true },
        email       : { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
        country     : { type: String, required: true },
        inventory   : {
            food : { type : Number, default : 0},
            energyDrinks : { type : Number, default : 0 }
        },
        wallet : [walletSchema],
        lastAttackedAt : { type: Date, default: Date.now },
        lastJobChange : {type: Date, default: '03/30/1988' },
        lastWorked : {type: Date},
        referredBy : {type : String, default : 'Admin'},
        energy      : { type: Number, default: 100 },
        energyUpdatedAt : { type : Date, default: Date.now },
        resetPasswordToken: String,
        resetPasswordExpires: Date
    }
},{timestamps : true});
```

I create a new user with this code :

```
...
newUser.local.username = capitalizeUser(username);
newUser.local.password = newUser.generateHash(password);
newUser.local.email = req.body.email;
newUser.local.country = req.body.country;
newUser.local.wallet.push({
        // Create the default currencies
        currencyName: 'Euro',
    }, {
        currencyName: 'Gold',
    }, {
        currencyName: result.countryCurrency
    }

);
// save the user
newUser.save(function(err) {
    if (err)
        throw err;
    return done(null, newUser);
});
```

Everything works fine for the first user however if I try to make another user I get `MongoError: insertDocument :: caused by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key error index: xyz.users.$local.wallet.currencyName_1  dup key: { : "Euro" }`.

Why is this happening, doesn't each user has it's own `wallet`? How should I handle it, keep in mind that there are about ~230 currencies available for each user.

Comment: As the error states, you have a duplicate `currencyName` `'Euro'`. Remove the `{unique : true}` attribute to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
currencyName : {type : String, required : true}
```

Remove unique from there and you will be good to go. Mongo checks unique keys for collection. In your case walletSchema collection will have a lot of same values so that's why it's gives error.

Answer (score 0):

As your currencyName has been set unique so it has to be different for each user you save. In fact you with this schema you won't even be able to have two users from the same country.

So to avoid this you need to remove the unique keyword from you schema and it is done. It then looks something like this.

```
var walletSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    currencyName : {type : String, required : true},
    amount : {type : Number, default : 0}
}, {strict : false});
```